# how to change label size dynamically using numericupdown in C#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to change label size using current value in numeric up-down list using C#

Comment: Size as in width? height? font?

Answer (score 1):

```
Label sample;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   sample = new Label();
   sample.Location = new Point(numericUpDown1.Left, numericUpDown1.Bottom);
   sample.Size = numericUpDown1.Size;
   sample.BackColor = Color.Blue;
   Controls.Add(sample);
   numericUpDown1.Value = sample.Width;
}

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sample.Width = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

If you mean font size then here's another sample:

```
Label sample;
Font sampleFont;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   sample = new Label();
   sample.Text = "Sample Text";
   sample.AutoSize = true;
   sample.Location = new Point(numericUpDown1.Left, numericUpDown1.Bottom);
   sample.Size = numericUpDown1.Size;
   sampleFont = (Font)Font.Clone();
   sample.Font = sampleFont;
   Controls.Add(sample);
   numericUpDown1.Value = (decimal)sampleFont.Size;
}

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Font newFont = new Font(sampleFont.FontFamily, (float)numericUpDown1.Value);
   sample.Font = newFont;
   sampleFont.Dispose();
   sampleFont = newFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Labels have the `AutoSize` property set to `true`. If you explicitly change it to `false`, you will be able to take control over the size.